# Fold up to the fold start, instead of the indent start

Tags: vim

I use `foldmethod=indent` and when I fold code like this:

```
def cake():
    #cake!
    print( "cake" )
    print( "for" )
    print( "you" )
```

I see

```
def cake():
    #cake!
    print( "cake" ) +++ 3 lines folded
```

but I want to see

```
def cake(): +++ 5 lines folded
```

Is there a way to do fold up to the first line (`def cake():`) like this?

Comment: I strongly recommend [this](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2527) script for python folding.  It worked very well for me for years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chapters [48](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/48.html) and [49](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/49.html) of *Learn Vimscript the Hard Way* talk about how to do that, using `foldmethod=expr` instead of `indent`. Basically you need to make a custom ftplugin and put a folding script in it; the script contains functions used to determine what fold level different lines should have.

As luck would have it, the example code given in those two chapters is for the Potion language which, like Python, is whitespace-sensitive, so it should be pretty easy to adapt it to Python. Since Vim already comes with a Python ftplugin, I think you can put the folding script described on the site into `.vim/after/ftplugin/python` instead of `.vim/ftplugin/potion`.

Comment: Oh man, this is exactly what I did just moments ago! Great advice.

Comment: Thanks for marking mine as the solution. You might have given it to yourself, since you go into specific detail.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this using [this tutorial](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/49.html).

This is the finished bunch of functions:

```
fu! Indent_level(lnum)
  return indent(a:lnum) / &shiftwidth
  endfunction

fu! Next_non_blank_line(lnum)
  let numlines = line('$')
  let current = a:lnum + 1

  while current <= numlines
    if getline(current) =~? '\v\S'
      return current
      endif
    let current += 1
    endwhile
  return -2
  endfunction

fu! Custom_fold_expr(lnum)
  if getline(a:lnum) =~? '\v^\s*$'
    return '-1'
    endif

  let this_indent = Indent_level(a:lnum)
  let next_indent = Indent_level(Next_non_blank_line(a:lnum))

  if next_indent == this_indent
    return this_indent
  elseif next_indent < this_indent
    return this_indent
  elseif next_indent > this_indent
    return '>' . next_indent
    endif
  endf

set foldexpr=Custom_fold_expr(v:lnum)
foldmethod=expr
```

Please don't edit the indentation of the "end" markers on this post, it looks gorgeous after you put this in your `vimrc`.